# are precautions against CSRF needed for view-only pages?

Tags: security, csrf, csrf-protection

All the examples of CSRF exploits tend to be against pages which process the incoming request.

If the page doesn't have a form processing aspect do I need to worry about CSRF ?

The situation I'm looking @ :

- the page in question contains sensitive data
- as such users need to establish a session to view the page

... my understanding is that a malicious page will be able to redirect a client to this page by embedding a link to it, however since there's no action on the target to perform there's no harm that can result, right ?

There's no way for said malicious site can *view* the sensitive page, correct ?

**Why I ask:** I want the url to the page with sensitive data to have a 'simple' URL which allows people to email the link to other people (who will in turn need a session to view the page). The token-based solution I've seen for most CSRF solutions remove this possibility, and so I'd like to avoid them if possible.

Comment: According to http://incompleteness.me/blog/2007/01/01/csrf-attacks-or-how-to-avoid-exposing-your-gmail-contacts/ it's implied that a script on the browser could re-direct the contents of the page to another server, which results in a leak of the data. But I'd thought that same-origin policy would prevent this leak, no ? **What am I missing ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, CSRF is independent from whether the request causes any side effects or not. The [CWE describes CSRF (CWE-352)](https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/352.html) as follows:

> The web application does not, or can not, sufficiently verify whether a well-formed, valid, consistent request was intentionally provided by the user who submitted the request.

So CSRF is a general request intention authenticity problem.

However, although CSRF is not really feasible without any effects other than data retrieval as the same-origin policy restricts the attacker from accessing the response, the attacker could exploit another vulnerability to profit from retrieval-only requests as well and gain access to sensitive data.

Comment: Actually, you're correct - "the attacker could exploit another vulnerability" covers a lot, and people who do things like this are smarter than I can imagine. So there goes my plan :-)

Comment: It depends on what format your data is in. The Gmail attack you liked to works as the GET request returned the data in a JavaScript function. A plain HTML page would normally be safe (but HTTPS is recommended), otherwise any page you read on the internet could be compromised by sites open in other tabs.

Answer (score 3):

> There's no way for said malicious site can view the sensitive page, correct ?

Correct in terms of CSRF.

The blog you linked is talking about Cross-Origin Script Inclusion, which is a different animal. To be vulnerable to XOSI your sensitive page would have to be interpretable as JavaScript, and you'd have to be either serving it without a proper HTML MIME type, or the browser would have to be an old one that didn't enforce type checking on scripts.

You might also potentially worry about clickjacking, where another site includes yours in a frame and overlays misleading UI elements. There are some sneaky ways that has been used to extract sensitive data (see the [next generation clickjacking](http://contextis.co.uk/files/Context-Clickjacking_white_paper.pdf) paper and [this](http://blog.saynotolinux.com/2014/02/05/whats-that-smell-sniffing-cross-origin-frames-in-firefox/) amusing info leak in Firefox) so you may wish to disallow framing with the `X-Frame-Options` header.

> Why I ask: I want the url to the page with sensitive data to have a 'simple' URL which allows people to email the link to other people (who will in turn need a session to view the page). The token-based solution I've seen for most CSRF solutions remove this possibility

You definitely shouldn't be putting a CSRF token in a GET URL. Apart from the ugliness, and breakage of navigation, URLs are easy to leak from the browser or other infrastructure, potentially compromising the confidentiality of the token.

Normal practice is not to put CSRF protection on side-effect-free actions.